# Writing to MySQL from a PHP array in a for loop

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, for-loop

I'm having a bit of trouble writing the contents of a PHP array to rows of a column in a MySQL table. Instead of updating each time through the loop, the same things gets inserted into the database again and again.

Here's the code (`$code` is an array of characters and `$code_length` is its length):

```
for ($counter = 0; $counter < $this->code_length; $counter++){
    $query = "INSERT INTO characters VALUES ('$this->code[$counter]')";
    mysql_query($query, $db_server);
}
```

If I execute it like this, it just puts the first element of `$code` on every line of the table. However, if I just change it to use a reference to the array element outside the SQL query instead it works. For example:

```
for ($counter = 0; $counter < $this->code_length; $counter++){
    $code_element = $this->code[$counter];
    $query = "INSERT INTO characters VALUES ('$code_element')";
    mysql_query($query, $db_server);
}
```

works fine and puts each new element of `$code` in a new row.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong in the first example or can you just not refer to array elements in that way in MySQL queries?

Comment: why dont you use foreach?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't looked at the docs for that - just learning from a (clearly out of date) book. I'll update to mysqli.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `{}` for using array in query

```
$query = "INSERT INTO characters VALUES ('{$this->code[$counter]}')";
```